# exact sequence problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let $B_1 \stackrel{f}{\to} B \stackrel{g}{\to} B_2 \to 0$ be an exact sequence. For any module $M$ the sequence $$0 \to \mbox{Hom}(B_2,M) \stackrel{g*}{\to} \mbox{Hom}(B,M) \stackrel{f*}{\to} \mbox{Hom}(B_1,M)$$ is exact.

Could anyone tell me if its true that  $$ \mbox{Im }g^*=\{a \in \mbox{Hom}(B,M):\ker g \subseteq \ker a\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the [fundamental theorem on homomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms).